# Exception calling "wait" with 1 argument in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wait, method-invocation

I've got a file with a few hundred servers where I need to check connection over a specific port.  The script I'm running is:

```
$connection = (New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient).ConnectAsync("$Hostname", $Port).Wait(1000)

    If($connection -eq 'True') {
        Write-Host "$Server can be reached on $Hostname over port $Port" -BackgroundColor Magenta
    }
    Else{
        Write-Host "$Server cannot be reached on $Hostname over port $Port" -BackgroundColor DarkCyan
    }
```

For the most of the servers I'm checking, this is working without issue.  Some come back successful, some not, but most return a valid value based on the query.  But for some reason I'm also seeing this error on quite a few attempts - and many of them seem to return a result as well:

```
Exception calling "Wait" with "1" argument(s): "One or more errors occurred."
At D:\File\PowerShell\PortCheck\PorteCheck.ps1:87 char:9
+         $connection = (New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Conne ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AggregateException
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `ConnectAsync` + `Wait` is not truly async. You can give this a try if you want truly async https://github.com/santysq/PowerShell-Network-Scanners/blob/main/Test-TCPConnectionAsync.ps1

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thanks for clarifying.  Just coping that code over and running it on it's own, I get the Source, Destination and Port columns all populated, but the Success column is blank.  Maybe I'm missing something, but it doesn't appear to be doing an actual connection test.

Comment: Oh my, seems like `.IsCompletedSuccessfully` is only on .NET Core. Thanks for letting me know. I have updated the code!

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon this worked beautifully!  I really only needed the success column as a variable so I ran  ---

$Hostname | Test-TCPConnectionAsync $Port -OutVariable connection | Out-Null

 --- Maybe there's an easier way, but that worked great.  Unfortunately, the site I had in mind when I started doing this is on PowerShell 2 and this script doesn't work for them.  Oh well, we're pushing them to do a hardware refresh anyhow, so it will work in the future!